# Oracle 19 / JSON query for sub-objects

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I try to extract data from a JSON API, but the structure is complex, with multiple sub-objects.
Getting data from the first data[*] is working well but NESTED PATH to access lower levels are not working.

Below a sample of data (it's a Stripe API answer).
I try to get the "receipt_url" data which is under data.charges.data.receipt_url path.

My query:

```
select 
    AMOUNT / 100, 
    CURRENCY, 
    receipt_url
from json_table (my_api_call,
                '$.data[*]'
                COLUMNS
                  (amount PATH '$.amount',
                  currency PATH '$.currency',
                  NESTED PATH '$.charges.data[*]' columns(receipt_url PATH '$.receipt_url') 
                  ));
```

The result: I have the correct number of rows, but receipt_url is empty.
I tried several syntaxes but non worked.
Thanks for you help!

The API return:

```
{
  "object": "search_result",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "pi_3MzKCmCUkkwhno",
      "object": "payment_intent",
      "amount": 76000,
      "amount_capturable": 0,
      "amount_details": {
        "tip": {}
      },
      "amount_received": 76000,
      "application": null,
      "application_fee_amount": null,
      "automatic_payment_methods": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "canceled_at": null,
      "cancellation_reason": null,
      "capture_method": "automatic",
      "charges": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "ch_3MzKCmCUdNN0hyU2x",
            "object": "charge",
            "amount": 76000,
            "amount_captured": 76000,
            "amount_refunded": 0,
            "application": null,
            "application_fee": null,
            "application_fee_amount": null,
            "balance_transaction": "txn_3MzKCmCUdNN0937n",
            "billing_details": {
              "address": {
                "city": "Aute enim saepe quas",
                "country": "CH",
                "line1": "Cumque aperiam dolor",
                "line2": null,
                "postal_code": "20285",
                "state": null
              },
              "email": "d@mailinator.com",
              "name": "Tatum Mcknight",
              "phone": "+1"
            },
            "calculated_statement_descriptor": "CUSTOMER",
            "captured": true,
            "created": 1682084467,
            "currency": "chf",
            "customer": null,
            "description": null,
            "destination": null,
            "dispute": null,
            "disputed": false,
            "failure_balance_transaction": null,
            "failure_code": null,
            "failure_message": null,
            "fraud_details": {},
            "invoice": null,
            "livemode": false,
            "metadata": {
              "record_id": "SAV-22-03392"
            },
            "on_behalf_of": null,
            "order": null,
            "outcome": {
              "network_status": "approved_by_network",
              "reason": null,
              "risk_level": "normal",
              "risk_score": 3,
              "seller_message": "Payment complete.",
              "type": "authorized"
            },
            "paid": true,
            "payment_intent": "pi_3MzKCmCU09kkwhno",
            "payment_method": "pm_1MzKD0CUdNN0hMWisdok",
            "payment_method_details": {
              "card": {
                "brand": "visa",
                "checks": {
                  "address_line1_check": "pass",
                  "address_postal_code_check": "pass",
                  "cvc_check": "pass"
                },
                "country": "US",
                "exp_month": 2,
                "exp_year": 2025,
                "fingerprint": "d95o6MttDVt7vHQm",
                "funding": "credit",
                "installments": null,
                "last4": "4242",
                "mandate": null,
                "network": "visa",
                "network_token": {
                  "used": false
                },
                "three_d_secure": null,
                "wallet": null
              },
              "type": "card"
            },
            "receipt_email": null,
            "receipt_number": null,
            "receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/payment/CAcaFwoVYWNjdF8xS09MRjhDVWROTjBoTTZVKNa2saMGMgdkFAIq4_8qCg6IPyLUCEUZDp",
            "refunded": false,
            "refunds": {
              "object": "list",
              "data": [],
              "has_more": false,
              "total_count": 0,
              "url": "/v1/charges/ch_3MzKCmCUdN7yU2x/refunds"
            },
            "review": null,
            "shipping": null,
            "source": null,
            "source_transfer": null,
            "statement_descriptor": null,
            "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
            "status": "succeeded",
            "transfer_data": null,
            "transfer_group": null
          }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 1,
        "url": "/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_3MzKCmC09kkwhno"
      },
      "client_secret": "pi_3MzKCmC09kkwhno_secret_LdWzl8QbK7Hw0",
      "confirmation_method": "automatic",
      "created": 1682084452,
      "currency": "chf",
      "customer": null,
      "description": null,
      "invoice": null,
      "last_payment_error": null,
      "latest_charge": "ch_3MzKCmCUdNNYW7yU2x",
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
        "record_id": "SAV-22-03392"
      },
      "next_action": null,
      "on_behalf_of": null,
      "payment_method": "pm_1MzKD0CUdNN0isdok",
      "payment_method_options": {
        "card": {
          "installments": null,
          "mandate_options": null,
          "network": null,
          "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
        }
      },
      "payment_method_types": [
        "card"
      ],
      "processing": null,
      "receipt_email": null,
      "review": null,
      "setup_future_usage": null,
      "shipping": null,
      "source": null,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
      "status": "succeeded",
      "transfer_data": null,
      "transfer_group": null
    },
    {
      "id": "pi_3MxsjECUdNNWbI3",
      "object": "payment_intent",
      "amount": 96000,
      "amount_capturable": 0,
      "amount_details": {
        "tip": {}
      },
      "amount_received": 96000,
      "application": null,
      "application_fee_amount": null,
      "automatic_payment_methods": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "canceled_at": null,
      "cancellation_reason": null,
      "capture_method": "automatic",
      "charges": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "ch_3MxsjECUdNN0hM1W3Aa",
            "object": "charge",
            "amount": 96000,
            "amount_captured": 96000,
            "amount_refunded": 0,
            "application": null,
            "application_fee": null,
            "application_fee_amount": null,
            "balance_transaction": "txn_3MxsjECUdNN1o34RM8m",
            "billing_details": {
              "address": {
                "city": "Maiores dolor eos o",
                "country": "CH",
                "line1": "Porro ut neque debit",
                "line2": null,
                "postal_code": "34151",
                "state": null
              },
              "email": "na@mailinator.com",
              "name": "Isadora Mayer",
              "phone": "+1 "
            },
            "calculated_statement_descriptor": "CUSTOMER",
            "captured": true,
            "created": 1681740524,
            "currency": "chf",
            "customer": null,
            "description": null,
            "destination": null,
            "dispute": null,
            "disputed": false,
            "failure_balance_transaction": null,
            "failure_code": null,
            "failure_message": null,
            "fraud_details": {},
            "invoice": null,
            "livemode": false,
            "metadata": {
              "record_id": "SAV-22-03392"
            },
            "on_behalf_of": null,
            "order": null,
            "outcome": {
              "network_status": "approved_by_network",
              "reason": null,
              "risk_level": "normal",
              "risk_score": 50,
              "seller_message": "Payment complete.",
              "type": "authorized"
            },
            "paid": true,
            "payment_intent": "pi_3MxsjECUU1koOWbI3",
            "payment_method": "pm_1MxsjXCUdNN4F6iBMi",
            "payment_method_details": {
              "card": {
                "brand": "visa",
                "checks": {
                  "address_line1_check": "pass",
                  "address_postal_code_check": "pass",
                  "cvc_check": "pass"
                },
                "country": "US",
                "exp_month": 4,
                "exp_year": 2024,
                "fingerprint": "d95o6MttDVt7vHQm",
                "funding": "credit",
                "installments": null,
                "last4": "4242",
                "mandate": null,
                "network": "visa",
                "network_token": {
                  "used": false
                },
                "three_d_secure": null,
                "wallet": null
              },
              "type": "card"
            },
            "receipt_email": null,
            "receipt_number": null,
            "receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/payment/CAcaFwoVYWNjdFXw6LBYe6v3ziFv1Ty-9gZJbRiaQqWI_sM9YRBojh2aMuHmG6F3",
            "refunded": false,
            "refunds": {
              "object": "list",
              "data": [],
              "has_more": false,
              "total_count": 0,
              "url": "/v1/charges/ch_3MxsjECUdNW3Aa/refunds"
            },
            "review": null,
            "shipping": null,
            "source": null,
            "source_transfer": null,
            "statement_descriptor": null,
            "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
            "status": "succeeded",
            "transfer_data": null,
            "transfer_group": null
          }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 1,
        "url": "/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_3MxsjECUdNWbI3"
      },
      "client_secret": "pi_3MxsjECUdNN0hbI3_secret_JxDUgRWc0fn8WyK8iQiKZOcRJ",
      "confirmation_method": "automatic",
      "created": 1681740504,
      "currency": "chf",
      "customer": null,
      "description": null,
      "invoice": null,
      "last_payment_error": null,
      "latest_charge": "ch_3MxsjECUdNN0hM6U1kI1W3Aa",
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
        "record_id": "SAV-22-03392"
      },
      "next_action": null,
      "on_behalf_of": null,
      "payment_method": "pm_1MxsjXCUdNN0hM6U84F6iBMi",
      "payment_method_options": {
        "card": {
          "installments": null,
          "mandate_options": null,
          "network": null,
          "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
        }
      },
      "payment_method_types": [
        "card"
      ],
      "processing": null,
      "receipt_email": null,
      "review": null,
      "setup_future_usage": null,
      "shipping": null,
      "source": null,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
      "status": "succeeded",
      "transfer_data": null,
      "transfer_group": null
    }
  ],
  "has_more": true,
  "next_page": "WzE2ODE3NDA1MDQuMDc0NDcyMl0=",
  "url": "/v1/payment_intents/search"
}
```

I tried several syntaxes, using '$', '$.[*]', direct path to the sub-object, none worked.

Comment: This is not JSON:API formatted data. You do not have a `type`, `attributes` or `relationships` keys at the top-level of the data resource and the resource is not in third-normal form (as you have nested data structures). This API pretends to do JSON:API at the top level and then misses out some of the more important features of JSON:API and is just JSON when you get to the data.

Comment: Your query works well and returns receipt URLs: https://dbfiddle.uk/t516_ok7/ What is your Oracle version?

Comment: We use Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.17.0.0.0

Comment: Regarding the formatting, this is the answer from Stripe. We juste have an Oracle function to query the API, and I use the result of this function in "my_api_call", with inside:                 UTL_HTTP.read_text(l_http_response, l_buffer, 32767);

                DBMS_LOB.writeappend(l_clob_response, length(l_buffer), l_buffer);

Comment: Finally I got the solution. I was mixing 2 Stripe tests environment in my API calls. And it seems these 2 are not configured the same way, explaining why I got a different response.